# Python recursively search through directories and only show files that contain a certain string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm looking to recursively search through directories and only show files that contain the string `"AWSTemplateFormatVersion"`.

```
import os, json

cfn = [".json", ".template", ".yaml", ".yml"]
dir = "./janitor"

def cloudFormation(dir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(tuple(cfn)):
                with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as fin:
                    data = fin.read()
                    print("************ Break **************")
                    print(data)
                    print(os.path.join(root, file))
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cloudFormation(dir)
```

Comment: `if "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" in data`?

Comment: Why not just use `grep -R`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? As Mike Müller suggests in comments, test for occurrence in `data`. Also, instead of printing the *last* `data` value, I've changed your code to return a list of all files with the conditions true:

```
import os, json

cfn = [".json", ".template", ".yaml", ".yml"]
dir = "./janitor"

def cloudFormation(dir):
    files_with_string = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(tuple(cfn)):
                with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as fin:
                    data = fin.read()
                    if "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" in data:
                        files_with_string.append(os.path.join(root, file))
                        print("************ Break **************")
                        print(data)
                        print(os.path.join(root, file))
    return files_with_string 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cloudFormation(dir)
```

I don't know how you want to implement it in your solution; i.e. the number and size of the files, but here are two notes:

If your files are big, then perhaps instead of reading the entire file, read only parts of the files incrementally.

If you have a lot of files, then perhaps make a generator function instead of returning a list of all file names.